# Bootstrap 480x320 320x480

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        Test testTest test <br />
        test <br />
        test test test
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        Test test testtesttest<br />
        test test<br />
        test test test
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        Test test testTest test<br />
        test testtesttest<br />
        test test test
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Why in bootstrap XS is not divided for 480x320 and 320x480 resolutions?

My example on 480x320 displays nicely but in 320x480 it is squeezed.

If I remove class col-xs-4 then each boxes in both resolutions are is in new line.

What it is the best way for this to boxes in resolution 480x320 were in one line and boxes in resolution 320x480 were in new lines.

Comment: May be you need `@landscape` in css to set its `width:100%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another class to the col and give it some full width css put this in your css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
  .col-tiny-12 {float:none; width:100%;}
}
```

and your html would look like

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-tiny-12">
        Test testTest test <br />
        test <br />
        test test test
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-tiny-12">
        Test test testtesttest<br />
        test test<br />
        test test test
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-tiny-12">
        Test test testTest test<br />
        test testtesttest<br />
        test test test
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```